# menu jumps after clicking menu item

Tags: html, css

I have this site http://www.eurotrend-dss.sk/ and i have problem with big orange menu.
If you click on EUROTREND DSS menu item, whole menu will jump a little bit. A can not find solution in css.
The jump is visible for me only in Chrome and Opera. In FF and IE it seems to be OK.
I think problem is with padding-top:10px, but i can not find solution not using this padding.

Comment: Which version of chrome did you tested? I don't see anything wrong with that site on Chrome v17.

Comment: I updated to v17 but problem is still there. Try clicking on first menu item EUROTREND DSS. I always "jumps"

Answer (score 0):

use margin-top instead of padding-top for the li

Comment: i tried but still "jumping" plus it has some problem with hover background.